# Access a complex data set in controller from a View's C# code block

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I set a complex data of a particular Model type. Now I want to access that in a View's code block.

I tried using HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<List>("productsInCart"); in code block, and also Context.Session.GetString("productsInCart").

I don't want to use ViewBag or it's related solution, because my controller action which sets complex data doesn't return a View.

Controller Method

```
public IActionResult GetProductByIdToAddInCart(GetProductInputModel model)
        { 
            var productById = _GetProductAPICall.GetProductsById(model); 
            var products = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<List<GetProductOutputModel>>("productsInCart");

            if(products != null && products.Count() != 0)
            {
                 products.Add(productById);
                HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("productsInCart", products.Distinct());
            }
            else
            {
                var firstProductInCart = new List<GetProductOutputModel>();
                firstProductInCart.Add(productById);
                HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("productsInCart", firstProductInCart);
            }

            var productsInCart = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<List<GetProductOutputModel>>("productsInCart");

            return Ok(new { data = productsInCart }); 
             
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the top of the view?  Did you set it with the `@model` keyword?

Comment: If your action that returns the data doesn't return a view, what _does_ return this View?  A different action?

Comment: Yes I set it with another model, which is different from the session one's

Comment: It sounds like you might need to call the action that _does_ return the data using an Ajax call.

Comment: It returns OkObjectResult type

Comment: @SuhaibAskar `OkObjectResult` has `Value` property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult.value?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-objectresult-value

Comment: Do you know both the data for the model you are using and the data that's in the session when you return the View? That is, is any information needed from the user in order to pull the data you want to display?

Comment: The issue is I want to access the complex data stored in server session in Layout.cshtml, moreover it already has one model set

Comment: You may need to use a more complex model. For example, you could use a `Tuple<T1, T2>`, and set the first property (`Item1`) to the model you need for most of the page, and the second property (`Item2`) to the data that's in the session. This kind of setup -- a model that's created just for the convenience of a View -- is sometimes called a `ViewModel`.

Comment: What happens when you use `HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<List>("productsInCart");`?  Do you get a Null back, or does it not recognize the code?

Comment: Thanks for the ViewModel suggestion, Doesn't recognise with a message "An object reference is required.... "

Comment: I give an example of creating the ViewModel in the answer below.

Comment: BTW, although I've been able to make some suggestions just from your description, it's usually a _lot_ easier to do so when you post some code that we can see!

Comment: Here you go, the code for controller method in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250412/discussion-between-suhaib-askar-and-ann-l).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo about how to use the complex data in session and display it in _Layout.cshtml:

Extension

```
namespace MvcProj.Services
{
    public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static void SetComplexData<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
        }

        public static T? GetComplexData<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default : System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Get the session in _Layout.cshtml

```
@using MvcProj.Models;    @*model namespace*@
@using MvcProj.Services;   @*extension namespace*@
@{        
    var data = Context.Session.GetComplexData<List<GetProductOutputModel>>("productsInCart");
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MvcProj</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/MvcProj.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MvcProj</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @if(data!=null)
            {
                <table>
                    @foreach(var item in data)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            }
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - MvcProj - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/myBundle.js"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);    
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();    
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();  //add this..

builder.Services.AddSession();    //add this..
var app = builder. Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseWebOptimizer();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();  //add this..

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

When you call the `GetProductByIdToAddInCart` method then it will display the data in each view which apply the _Layout.cshtml as Layout.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options, as I see it.

It sounds as if, when you return the `View`, you already have the complex data in `Session`. If that's the case, you can simply put it in `ViewBag` from within the action that returns the View.

Or, you can use a more complex model, like so:

```
var model = new Tuple<MyModel, List<Product>>(
   myModel,
   HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<List<Product>>("productsInCart") 
);
Return MyView(model);
```

(I am assuming a model called `MyModel` and that the complex data is a `List<Product>`.)

If you do that, you will have to change the definition of the `@model` from within the View, to reflect that it's a different type now.

You would refer to the new model from within the View like this:

```
%foreach(var record in model.Item2) { 
  <div><%= record.ProductId %></div>
```

... etc.

Alternatively, you could use some Ajax code to make a call to the controller that returns the complex data, but that's usually something that's triggered by an action from the user, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Yes Ajax is the last resort, earlier I set a string in controller session and accessed it in View's code block with `Context.Session.GetString("sampleString")`. But complex data in session is what I wanted to do.